# How to bring an Activity to foreground? Nothing work from inside a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, foreground

I have an activity that receives SMS and I would like it to be brought to the foreground when that happens. It doesn't matter if it is the same instance or a new one. I've tried everything I found in this site, even other flags like FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK works fine, but [so far] NOTHING brings the Activity to the foreground.

```
public class SMSMessenger extends Activity {
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private BroadcastReceiver   yourReceiver;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
        theFilter.addAction(ACTION);

        this.yourReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                // Bring activity to the foreground - doesn't work
                Intent I = new Intent(context, SMSMessenger.class);
                I.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                context.startActivity(I);
                //------------------------------------------------
            }
        };
        this.registerReceiver(this.yourReceiver, theFilter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is this.  Create your receiver as a seperate file (MyBroadcastReceiver.java) and have it launch the activity or popup a notification or whatever.  In your AndroidManifest try putting this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name=
            "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Also make sure you include the SMS permission in your AndroidManifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Comment: I tried that, if by a popup you mean a toast, it works fine. But what I want is that my activity to opens/resume.

Comment: I was actually refering to Notifications.  see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Itd been a while since I work with broadcast receivers and I remember now you cannot bind to a service/launch an activity with them.

Create a notification with a pending intent of the activity that you wish to launch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
    myManager       = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    myNotification  = new Notification(R.drawable.alert1, "ALERT...!!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    myIntent        = new Intent(context, SmsMessanger.class);
    myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
    myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "NEW SMS ALERT...!!", "You have a new SMS alert..!! Click here to stop the alert tone...!!", myPendingIntent);
    myManager.notify(0, myNotification);
```

It worked for me..!

when we click on the notification, the activity is brought to front.